# Can I compile 2 build templates in the same solution?

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

I've got a class library project set up to do template editing and wanted to drop in another copy and customize it. However I get

`The type 'TfsBuild.Process' already contains a definition for '_contentLoaded'`

and 22 more of the same with the other _ names.

Also `Type 'TfsBuild.Process' already defines a member called 'Process' with the same parameter types   C:\Projects\MSBuild.Tasks\TechnicalDebtTaskLib\BuildProcessTemplate\obj\Release\CodeMetric.g.cs 62  16  BuildProcessTemplate`

i've tried hand editing different parts of the xaml to try to find what key might need to be more unique, but no luck.

How do I work on multiple build process templates in the same solution or copy a process template that makes it unique?

Comment: Please be more clear. What do you mean, "set up to do template editing"? What are the exact steps that you followed?

Comment: I copied the default template into the project, then made a copy of it to do a different build type.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Summary:

```
<activity mc:ignorable="sap" x:class="Tfs2008Template.Process" ... xmlns:this="clr-namespace:Tfs2008Template">
```

two tags must be changed for example:

```
<activity mc:ignorable="sap" x:class="Tfs2008Template2.Process" ... xmlns:this="clr-namespace:Tfs2008Template2">
```

For whatever reasoning the two tags that are related and need to be in sync are usually at the beginning and end of a very long list of attributes.

Full Article on [my blog](http://imaginarydevelopment.blogspot.com/2011/05/coping-tfs2010-build-template-into-same.html)

Comment: The two tags are namespace and class declarations; if there are two instances of process templates in the same assembly that have identical values for these, there would be two insances of the same class in the binary created at compiletime. The fix described above is simply placing one of the process templates in a different namespace to prevent collisions.